# How to protect fixed cupboards from termites

Tags: plywood, maintenance, protection, termite

I have a cupboard which is made of plywood and it's permanently fixed with the room wall and floor.

[image: model image]

My neighbour has expressed that his cupboard got affected with Termites so I just want to be taking all the preventive steps.

I can look after the plywood from the sides that's visible but what about the side that's on the wall which is not visible.

Are there any standard approaches to deal with this challenge ?

My gut feeling is drill some hole into plywood and inject some Anti termite liquids on the wall side.

Any ideas or standard practises or maintenance practices ?

Comment: that one looks like a tougher than normal DIY job, might be best to call out a bug guy and have it treated as a preventative measure/peace of mind.

Comment: @dandavis - As per him he wants to dismantle the complete structure and apply some anti termite coating .. I think this I can't afford because once in 5 years or something I have to dismantle and it's all glued together. I'm looking for some clever approach to deal with this predicament.

Comment: A little more context might help. Is the neighbour living on an adjacent station in the outback, e.g. within 100km of you, or is there a common wall between the two of you?

Comment: @HABO - His house is like 20 feet away from my house

Answer (score 1):

- Buy some digital termite scanners which can scan and tell you if there's any termite
- Keep your ear on the plywood .. you might hear some sound if worker termites are on their way up
- Try to keep the room dry and less humid so it won't attract the termites.
- Keep your rooms clean and neat.
- If you see any activity , take the plywoods apart and apply anti termite coating and assemble it back.

This is not a great solution but it's something

Comment: Digital termite scanner ? Is it accurate ? Seems like an expensive option for me